# Is masturbation allowed for medical purposes

Tags: halal-haram, medical, masturbation

We know istimna is haraam in Islam. But there is a certain medical condition for which sometimes doctors prescribe the patients to do that regularly.

Now I was wondering, say a person had a wife who died and he cannot marry again because he still loves his previous wife. But he suffers this kind of disease and is prescribed to do either intercourse or istimna regularly. Now a halaal solution here would be to marry again for this purpose. But is that really a solution, considering marrying again would destroy him mentally and his love, and he knows very well he cannot love his second wife?

Does he *have* to marry just for a physical treatment? Or in that situation, can he do istimna, just for the sake of the treatment, and not for enjoyment or anything?

Comment: > considering marrying again would destroy him mentally and his love, and he knows very well he cannot love his second wife? This sentence is totally false. You can never know what will happen if he does something in the future.

Comment: what kind of illness is this, you asked the question give us precise references so we can provide an answer!!!

Comment: Is this even an actual practical concern, or are you asking for a [completely hypothetical ruling for a completely hypothetical person suffering a completely hypothetical disease](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/338/22) here?

Comment: Frequent emission of seamen can actually help with certain prostate conditions, I think, @goldPseudo, so this may not be purely hypothetical.

Comment: i think there can be some disease because of too much food is consumed. i think there is better solution in islam: additional fasting, so , there is no need for masturbation.